# É possível instanciar uma classe sem chamar o construtor no PHP?

Tags: php

É possível instanciar uma classe em PHP sem que a classe chame o método `__construct`?

Exemplo:

```
class Test {

     public $chamado = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
          $this->chamado = true;
    }
}


$teste = new Test;

var_dump($teste->chamado); //bool(true);
```

Como chamar essa classe sem que `chamado` seja mudado para `true`, por exemplo?

Existe essa possibilidade em PHP?

Comment: Sim é possível, acredite!

Comment: Ficaria mais simples se não definisses um método `construct`.

Comment: Foi o que o Ivan respondeu. Também concordo. Mas de qualquer forma, vale a curiosidade ;)

Comment: Se achar que o titulo ficou ruim faça o rollback por favor.

Comment: O método que especificaste abaixo vai causar alguns problemas para algumas pessoas que pouco entendem o uso dos construtores, seria bom que explicasses apresentasses um porquê e quando deve-se fazer isto.

Answer (score 4):

Através da classe de reflexão de classes `ReflectionClass` é possível sim fazer isso em php.

Exemplo:

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass('Test')

$test = $reflect->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

var_dump($test->chamado); // bool(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

O método construtor não é obrigatório para criar uma instância da classe, ele é feito somente para setar os valores iniciais quando for criar a sua instância. Isso ocorre quando ele invoca o construtor, o construtor pode ser definido de duas formas:

Assim:

```
class SuaClasse
{
  private $chamado = false;

  public function __construct()
  {
    //o que será construído junto à instância
      $this->chamado = true;
  }

  public function setChamado($boolean)
  {
     $this->chamado = $boolean;
     return $this;
  }

  public function getChamado()
  {
     return $this->chamado;
  }
}
```

ou assim:

```
class SuaClasse
{
  private $chamado = false;

  public function SuaClasse()
  {
    //o que será construído junto à instância
    $this->chamado = true;
  }

  public function getChamado()
  {
     return $this->chamado;
  }
}
```

Há também o método destruidor:

```
class SuaClasse
{
  private $chamado = false;

  public function __destruct()
  {
    //o que será destruído junto à instância
    $this->chamado = true;
  }
}
```

Você não precisa, necessariamente, criar um método construtor da classe na instância, também não precisa se preocupar com que o método construtor defina sua saída:

```
$suaClasse = new SuaClasse;
```

Você pode setar os valores:

```
//será false
$suaClasse->setChamado(false);
echo $suaClasse->getChamado();
//será true
$suaClasse->setChamado(true);
echo $suaClasse->getChamado();
```

Diretamente, para chamar o construtor, seria assim:

```
 $suaClasse = new SuaClasse();
 //será true
 echo $suaClasse->getChamado();
```

Uma outra maneira de fazer o construtor trabalhar em prol da sua necessidade, é ele definir como vai começar:

```
class SuaClasse
{
  private $chamado = false;

  public function __construct($boolean)
  {
    //o que será construído junto à instância
      $this->chamado = $boolean;
  }

  public function getChamado()
  {
     return $this->chamado;
  }

} 

$suaClasse = new SuaClasse(true);
//será true
$suaClasse->getChamado();

$suaClasse = new SuaClasse(false);
//será false
$suaClasse->getChamado();
```

Comment: Entendo sua visão. Mas aí está mais relacionado à declaração da classe do que com a instanciação sem chamar o `__construct`. E também não faz sentido alguém querer instanciar uma classe sem o construtor (pelo menos não vem a mente nenhum caso assim) +1

Comment: Só um detalhe, sobre o construtor estilo php4,  no php7 esse estilo vai retornar um [warning E_DEPRECATED](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php), no php5 caso a classe esteja dentro de um namespace o método de mesmo nome(construtor estilo php4) será tratado como um método normal, como dito na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) e +1 pela boa resposta.

Comment: A propósito, o PHP 7 foi lançado oficialmente ontem.

Comment: Você fala do nome da classe como método... pois é, por isso é bom evitar isso.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, concordo é bom evitar mesmo, assim já vai pegando o jeito para quando pegar o php7 :P, veja por quanto tempo a galera usa funções depreciadas depois que são removidas é só choro.